# visualizing PCM data streamed over a peer connection in realtime?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, web-audio-api, waveform

I have an experimental sound project I'm working on that streams PCM audio data over a webRTC connection.

Unfortunately I have to do some special processing to the raw data before sending it over the stream, so I haven't been able to pipe the stream directly over webRTC.  Instead I do processing in the `ScriptProcessorNode`

I know that `ScriptProcessorNode` has been deprecated in favor of `AudioWorkerNode`  Essentially I am doing the same thing because I have a web worker which processes the script processor node's data.

This processed data is then sent over webRTC, which I want to visualize and interact with on the other end.

I came across several repos that do this kind of thing but I can't seem to find one that works efficiently with real-time peer streamed data.

wavesurfer-js.org/
works great but only loads full audio files, not streamed data.  I was able to manipulate the library a little bit to be able to update the waveform visualization with live stream data, but the way I'm doing it is not performant.

https://github.com/bbc/waveform-data.js + https://github.com/bbc/peaks.js
This one looks promising and I have yet to try it. Lots of features for interacting with the waveform.

github.com/soundcloud/waveformjs
Works well and has an 'update' function that is performant, but the library is not being maintained and doesn't support much functionality beyond viewing the waveform.

Does anyone have any experience with a good library for this purpose?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm looking for a way to stream an audio file to peaks.js for an in-browser waveform